# python constructor of derived class

Tags: python, derived-class, super, base-class

```
class baseClass():
  def __init__(self,mark,name):
    self.mark = mark
    self.name = name

class derivedClass(baseClass):

b1 = derivedClass(name='Jibin')
print b1.name
```

This was my code initially & it worked fine.

(Note: I don't have access to `baseClass`)

But later I had to pass a additional attribute `rank` to `derivedClass`.So I edited the code like this.

```
class baseClass():
  def __init__(self,mark,name):
    self.mark = mark
    self.name = name

class derivedClass(baseClass):
  def __init__(self,rank):
    self.rank = rank 

b1 = derivedClass(name='Jibin')
print b1.name
```

This caused an error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

This was expected as the `__init__` of `derivedClass` do not have a argument `name`.

I don't want to add an additional argument `name` to `__init__` of `derivedClass` b'cos in real `baseClass` has ten arguments instead of 2(mark,name) & if i give all them as additional argument to  `derivedClass` I will be cluttering its argument list.

Note: I am aware of initializing baseClass using `baseClass.__init__(self)` or `super(derivedClass, self).__init__()`

Comment: Your code as written is horribly broken. Please verify that the anonymized code still **works** before submitting it.

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) would like you to rename `baseClass` to `BaseClass`, `derivedClass` to `DerivedClass` and put in spaces after the commas in the arguments of the method declarations.

Comment: currently, the derived class has no relation to your base class. And why do not you use new-style classes?

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams .It has nothing to do with **anonymity**.I was working in django & I came across this problem.I knew its a python problem.So there was no need to put all the complexities of django forms & views in here.Nevertheless my apologies for the broken code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
class BaseClass(object):
  def __init__(self, mark=None, name=None):   # you're using named parameters, declare them as named one.
    self.mark = mark
    self.name = name

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):   # don't forget to declare inheritance
  def __init__(self, rank=None, *args, **kwargs):    # in args, kwargs, there will be all parameters you don't care, but needed for baseClass
    super(DerivedClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.rank = rank 

b1 = DerivedClass(name='Jibin')
print b1.name
```

Comment: Thanks.But  what is it with `# you're using named parameters, declare them as named one.`.If I don't give default values to arguments it won't be named arguments?

Comment: @Jibin : you call `derivedClass(name='Jibin')`, this is a named parameter, it is more coherent if you declare this parameter as a named one.

Comment: Its just that I don't wan't to give default values to arguments to make it required arguments.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://www.memonic.com/user/pneff/folder/python/id/1tHgm) describes how to solve this sort of problem. The solution is to have `base` as well as `derived` accept a `**kwargs` argument in their `__init__` and pass that to the call to `super`.

Answer (score 0):

`derivedClass` is *not* in fact derived from `baseClass`. To subclass in python you must provide the parent class to the class definition thus:

```
class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    pass
```

`DerivedClass` now inherits the methods of BaseClass, *including* `__init__()`. If you do not override a method, calling it on your subclass actually calls the method as defined on the superclass.

So, if you want to allow `DerivedClass(name='Jibin')`, you need to provide a specialised **init**():

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, mark, name):
        self.mark = mark
        self.name = name

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, mark, name, rank):
        BaseClass.__init__(self, mark, name)
        self.rank = rank
```

Now, you also want to support additional keyword arguments to `DerivedClass()` *without* adding them explicitly. One way to achieve this is to assign all `kwargs` to instance attributes, thus:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, mark, name, **kwargs):
        self.mark = mark
        self.name = name
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

I don't advise this 'for real' though. Blindly setting attributes is likely to introduce subtle bugs in the future (such things as unknowingly replacing a method by passing a keyword arg of the same name)

Answer (score 0):

Have you guys tried 
[[Python] cast base class to derived class](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=877526)

I have tested it, and seems it works. Also I think this method is bit better than below one since below one does not execute **init** function of derived function.

```
c.__class__ = CirclePlus
```